# Find the inverse Laplace transform of: $\frac{1}{(s^2+a^2)(s^2+b^2)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm having trouble doing this homework problem because I'm not sure how to deal with the $a$ and $b$. I did it the usual way we were taught - use partial fraction decomposition and then try to solve for the coefficients. When I solved for them, this is the conclusion I came to:

$$
\frac{A}{B}=\frac{-a^2}{b^2}
$$

Thus my original problem becomes 
$$
\frac{-a^2}{(s^2+a^2)}+\frac{b^2}{(s^2+b^2)}
$$

But I'm stuck here. I know that the inverse of $\frac{a}{(s^2+a^2)}$ is $sin(at)$ but I'm not sure if I can use that here....

Also, is there another way of solving this without using partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Yes you want to use that (just factor out $a$) but you made a slight mistake. If you add those terms together, you'll see your coefficients are off.

Comment: Ok I'm really stuck on the partial decomp part then. I think my mistake was that I forgot that the bottom two terms are irreducible, so the split should look like $\frac{As+B}{(s^2+a^2)}+\frac{Bs+C}{(s^2+b^2)}$. When $s=0$, this results in $\frac{B}{C}=\frac{-a^2}{b^2}$ but now I'm stuck on finding $A$. I narrowed it down to $A=\frac{1+2a^2+a^4-b^2}{(1+b^2)}$, but how do I then go about solving for $A$?

Answer (score 1):

Your partial fractions decomposition is off. You should get
$$
\frac{1}{(s^2+a^2)(s^2+b^2)} = \frac{1}{b^2-a^2} \left( \frac{1}{s^2+a^2} - \frac{1}{s^2+b^2} \right),
$$
so the inverse Laplace transform is
$$
\frac{1}{b^2-a^2} \left( \frac1a \sin at - \frac1b \sin bt \right).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just note $$\frac{1}{s^2+a^2}-\frac{1}{s^2+b^2}=\frac{b^2-a^2}{(s^2+a^2)(s^2+b^2)}$$
Then, if $a^2\neq b^2$ and $ab\neq 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(s^2+a^2)(s^2+b^2)}&=\frac{\frac{1}{b^2-a^2}}{s^2+a^2}-\frac{\frac{1}{b^2-a^2}}{s^2+b^2}\\
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{(s^2+a^2)(s^2+b^2)}\right\}&=\frac{1}{a(b^2-a^2)}\sin(at)-\frac{1}{b(b^2-a^2)}\sin(bt)
\end{align*}

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around how you made that first claim but I don't see how you got there. My first step would have just been to use partial fraction decomp, yet it seems like you bypassed that completely. How did you realize that first part? Could you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: @DarthVoid: Since $$\frac{1}{(s^2+a^2)(s^2+b^2)}$$ has only a constant term on the numerator, it seems to me it is easy regard a difference of fractions (instead of writing an solve a system of linear equations)
$$\frac{1}{s^2+a^2}-\frac{1}{s^2+b^2}=\frac{s^2+b^2-(s^2+a^2)}{(s^2+a^2)(s^2+b^2)}=\frac{b^2-a^2}{(s^2+a^2)(s^2+b^2)}$$

Comment: @DarthVoid : There are two common ways to write $\frac{1}{AB}$: $$\frac{1}{A+B}\left(\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}\right)\mbox{ and } \frac{1}{AB}=\frac{1}{B-A}\left(\frac{1}{A}-\frac{1}{B}\right).$$ If $A=s^{2}+a^{2}$ and $B=s^{2}=b^{2}$, which one works out better? Better to cancel the $s^{2}$ terms with $A-B$, right?

Answer (score 0):

As you said,
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}\right)=\sin(at)\tag{1} $$
hence, assuming $a\neq b$ and $a,b\neq 0$:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{(s^2+a^2)(s^2+b^2)}\right)&=&\frac{1}{b^2-a^2}\cdot\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s^2+a^2}-\frac{1}{s^2+b^2}\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{b^2-a^2}\left(\frac{\sin(at)}{a}-\frac{\sin(bt)}{b}\right)\\&=&\color{red}{\frac{b\sin(at)-a\sin(bt)}{ab(b^2-a^2)}}.\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$